# Lambda in constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class which uses lambda in one of its constructor, and I am having trouble understanding how it gets executed

```
using pred = std::function<bool(int)>;
using pred_list = std::vector<pred>;

class check
{
    private:
        std::string const _description;
    public:
        check(std::string, msec duration = msec{0});
        check(std::string, pred_list, msec duration = msec{0});
        check(std::string, pred, msec duration = msec{0});
};
```

The constructors

```
check::check(std::string d, pred_list p, msec dur)
: _description{d}, _duration{dur}, _predicates{p}, _pred_pass{false}
, _deadline{msec::max()}
{};

check::check(std::string d, pred p, msec dur)
: _description{d}, _duration{dur}, _predicates{1,p}, _pred_pass(false)
{};

check::check(std::string s, msec dur)
: check(s, [](int i) { return i > 0; }, dur) 
{};
```

Constructor in question

```
check::check(std::string s, msec dur)
: check(s, [](int i) { return i > 0; }, dur) 
{};
```

If I create an object of type check using the following

```
check db_intl{"Test", db_dur};
```

The following constructor gets called

```
check::check(std::string s, msec dur)
: check(s, [](int i) { return i > 0; }, dur) 
{};
```

How is this constructor able to call the other constructor with the lambda if that lambda is not being used?

Answer (score 1):

Since `pred` is typedefed to `std::function<bool(int)>`, the lambda will be converted to a `pred`, and construction is then delegated to the 3rd constructor (`check(std::string, pred, msec duration = msec{0})`.  The lambda will then be stored in the `_predicates` container and (presumably) called later when the predicates are invoked.

Comment: _predicates is defined as
    `pred_list const _predicates;`
If i create an object of type check like this
    `check db_intl{"Test", db_dur};`
It is only passing 2 parameters, and in the third constructor there is no local variable which can be used for the lambda

Comment: @zer0c00l The two parameter constructor will delegate to the three parameter one; see the "Delegating constructor" section on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).  The lambda is not using any local variables.